# How to get permanent Facebook session (IN FACEBOOK PHP SDK 4.0) in other pages for Facebook page tab application?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have implemented the new facebook API v 4.0.0 on my project & all functionality is working properly in my landing page(Facebook page tab application redirect URL page). I am able to get Facebook session & Facebook user data. But whenever I submit my details through facebook page tab & going to the next page I lost facebook session & unable to fetch facebook user data.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.